# ServiceBus Trigger not binding CorrelationId

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Function which is using a ServiceBus trigger with topics.  I recently added correlationId to the list of bindable inputs however the correlationId is not binding.  I have confirmed that the correlationId is set corectly on the inbound message.  All tooling/NuGets are on the latest bits (as of today).

The function also happens to be a durable function as is obvious in the following code snippet

```
[FunctionName("TopicHandler")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "SubscriptionName", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]string messageBody,
        string label,
        string messageId,
        string correlationId,
        IDictionary<string, object> userProperties,
        [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ExecutionContext executionContext,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        ....
```

Documetnation seems to imply this should work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---message-metadata

However this is not completely explict as to whether it only works with queues or not.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads#message-routing-and-correlation

Any guidance would be appreciated before I create a custom property.

Comment: There seems no problem with the binding data, a quick sample works on my side. Could you elaborate on how you send the message?

Comment: In production code, I use a TopicClient instance to send messages.  However, the symptoms exist when I use the "Service Bus Explorer" utility as well so I would assume it's not how the message is being sent.

Comment: Agree, but I am not able to repro the symptom. Could you provide the project file(.csproj) and Function host/Cli version?

Comment: Before I do that, could you share your trigger function definition (as I did above)?

Comment: I figured out the issue.  Turns out it wasn't the binding at all.  Your earlier comment about sender got me to thinking about how the response message was being created and I eventually found the issue there.  Pilot error.